# How to properly quote a PowerShell command path when used from CMD

Tags: powershell, cmd

**Baseline command that works properly:**

The following command is being executed in CMD prompt and runs successfully.

```
"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6.0.4\pwsh.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command "&{D:\FooBar\myscript.ps1 -DependentAssembliesDirectoryPath 'D:\FooBar' -OutputPath 'D:\Baz Qux\output' -DocumentVersion 'whatever' -VisualStudioXmlDocumentationPaths 'D:\Baz Qux\input\my.xml' -AssemblyPaths  'D:\Baz Qux\input\my.exe','D:\Baz Qux\input\my1.dll','D:\Baz Qux\input\my2.dll','D:\Baz Qux\input\my3.dll' -MajorOpenApiSpecificationVersion 3 -MinorOpenApiSpecificationVersion 0 -Format YAML -DocumentDescriptionFilePath 'D:\Baz Qux\input\my.md'}; EXIT $LASTEXITCODE"
```

However, when a space is introduced to the path of `myscript.ps1`, the command no longer works. This is expected since I need to properly quote the path. I cannot figure out the proper way of quoting though.

**Invalid attempt at quoting the command:**

I thought this would have worked based on the technique of quoting other paths in my command, but this doesn't work.

```
"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6.0.4\pwsh.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command "&{'D:\Foo Bar\myscript.ps1' -DependentAssembliesDirectoryPath 'D:\Foo Bar' -OutputPath 'D:\Baz Qux\output' -DocumentVersion 'whatever' -VisualStudioXmlDocumentationPaths 'D:\Baz Qux\input\my.xml' -AssemblyPaths  'D:\Baz Qux\input\my.exe','D:\Baz Qux\input\my1.dll','D:\Baz Qux\input\my2.dll','D:\Baz Qux\input\my3.dll' -MajorOpenApiSpecificationVersion 3 -MinorOpenApiSpecificationVersion 0 -Format YAML -DocumentDescriptionFilePath 'D:\Baz Qux\input\my.md'}; EXIT $LASTEXITCODE"
```

This command results in a bunch of errors like,

```
At line:1 char:119
+ ... ionsDocumentGeneration.ps1' -DependentAssembliesDirectoryPath 'D:\Ope ...
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '-DependentAssembliesDirectoryPath' in expression or statement.

At line:1 char:153
+ ... rectoryPath 'D:\Foo Bar' -OutputPath ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token ''D:\Foo Bar'' in expression or statement.
```

Again, since it can be a little hard to see the difference, the delta from the baseline command that works and the second command is that `&{D:\FooBar\myscript.ps1` changed to `&{'D:\Foo Bar\myscript.ps1'` to introduce a space in the path and attempt quoting.

**Please Note**

I cannot invoke the command in PowerShell because it is out of my control. It must be invoked in cmd.exe prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that **you need to use `&` in PowerShell in order to invoke a command name / executable file path that is *quoted* and/or specified via a *variable***:

Therefore, replace:

```
"&{'D:\Foo Bar\myscript.ps1' ... }; exit $LASTEXITCODE"
```

with:

```
"& { & 'D:\Foo Bar\myscript.ps1' ... }; exit $LASTEXITCODE"
```

That said, there's no reason to wrap the invocation of your `*.ps1` script in a script-block invocation (`& { ... }`), so you can simplify your command to:

```
"& 'D:\Foo Bar\myscript.ps1' ...; exit $LASTEXITCODE"
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra tip about simplifying the command and explaining how it works. Love it when the community shares knowledge like this beyond just the code that'll get the job done.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @ScottLin; my pleasure.